# How to remove notification when service stopped?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notifications

**Code i'm using now is this:**

```
private void removeNotification(){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(Constants.CHANNEL_ID.CHANNEL_ID);
    }
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.cancel(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.SERVICE_ID);
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Notification removed!");
}
```

But what is the difference between my code and `stopForeground(true);` ?
Because it both removes the notification.

Which one should i use when my service gets destroyed?

**EDIT**

Notification code:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.CHANNEL_ID.CHANNEL_ID);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel =
                new NotificationChannel(
                        Constants.CHANNEL_ID.CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Media PlayBack",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        notificationBuilder.setChannelId(Constants.CHANNEL_ID.CHANNEL_ID);
    }
    notificationBuilder.setShowWhen(false)
            .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mMediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken()).setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_headset).setContentTitle(activeSong.getTitle()).setContentText(activeSong.getArtist())
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_prev_white, null, playbackAction(3))
            .addAction(notificationAction, null, play_pause_action).addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_next_white, null, playbackAction(2))
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close, null, playbackAction(4))
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme1));

    notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);

    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.SERVICE_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Code i'm using now is this

Do not delete the channel.

> But what is the difference between my code and stopForeground(true); ?

`stopForeground(true)` only works if you used `startForeground()`.

> Which one should i use when my service gets destroyed?

If you used `startForeground()`, use `stopForeground()`. If you raised the `Notification` directly using `NotificationManager`, `cancel()` the `Notification` using `NotificationManager`.

Comment: @Vince: You are not calling `show()` on `NotificationManager` to show the `Notification`. You are using `startForeground()`. So, use `stopForeground()` to remove the `Notification`.

Comment: @Vince: When you are showing the `Notification`, you are using `NotificationManager` to create the channel. That will still be needed when that channel does not already exist, so you need to keep that code.